# How to identifying important nodes in communities with igraph package?

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to find influential nodes in community with igraph pakage in R

First I find the communities with for example newman algorithm (cluster_edge_betweetness), after that I don't know how to apply any centralities (betweennes or degree, etc.) in communities that I could identify important nodes in each communities.!

Is there a command to find out how can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Having an example makes it easier to answer your question. See here on how to make a great reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610